# Google Drive API check json response after upload

Tags: python, json, google-api, google-drive-api

Looking for best practice here. I am uploading a file to a folder, and then wanting to check if the json response is good using an if statement.

```
def upload_report(report,save_folder_id,http):
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
    head, tail = os.path.split(report)
    file_metadata = {
        'name' : tail,
        'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
        'parents' : [ folder_id ]
}
media = MediaFileUpload(report,mimetype='application/vnd.google-apps.document',resumable=True)
gfile = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,media_body=media,fields='id').execute()
```

So essentially, if the json response validates successful upload, return true, else, return false. What would be best practice to accomplish this?

Pardon such a rudimentary question, still new to using the api with python.

Answer (score 0):

and this is why I don't like libraries!

The documentation should describe how errors are presented, ideally at https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/python/latest/drive_v2.files.html#insert

To confirm if the insert succeeded, checking `file` for a string in the `id` property would suffice. Unfortunately that doesn't answer your next question which will be "if there is an error, how do I find out what it is, so I can deal with it correctly?".

Hopefully somebody who's used the Python lib can provide more info.

Comment: Yeah exactly my thoughts, but yes hopefully someone gets back to me. 
I mean there are a lot of other ways to accomplish this end (for one, not using Python!), but I'm just curious at this point. Thanks for your response though!